# MVC 5 Delete/Exclude certain parts of return model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have alot of [HttpPost] methods that returns data to my view. They all look something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> NewAction(Action model)
{     
    object[] data = new object[5];

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            Case case = db.Cases.Find(model.Case_ID);
            model.Created = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            model.Created_date = DateTime.Now;
            model.Active = true;

            case.Actions.Add(model);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            data[0] = true;
            data[1] = "Action added!";
            data[2] = model;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            data[0] = false;
            data[3] = ex.Message;
            data[4] = ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : "No details";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string errors = string.Join("<br/>", ModelState.Values
                                .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                                .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));

        data[0] = false;
        data[3] = "<b>Invalid input data</b>";
        data[4] = errors;
    }

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

So here i return the model in the data[2] object so I can extract data from this and put it in to my tables. The problem is that I have to return the Created object to get the Users Firstname and LastName. But the problem is that the Created object is a ApplicationUser object so this also includes fields from IdentityUser like PasswordHash, SecurityStamp etc which I dont want to return in the response.

So.. is there an easy way to exclude/include only some parts of the object? Or do I have to create a new object and only assign the values I want to return?

Comment: You would be far better off creating a view model which represents only the properties you want to display/edit but you can also use the [BindAttribute.Exclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.exclude(v=vs.118).aspx) property

Comment: And you should avoid using special names like `case` for a variable!

Comment: Hmmm yea thats true. Will be alooot of ViewModels for new/edit/delete though, but I think I like that best :)

Comment: Yea, I am actually, just renamed that for demo purposes ;)

Comment: Hmmmm the only problem I get though is that I have to create a new object of Action, since now the model I send in doesn't match the Action model in the database so I cant just add the model to the DB.. So then I have to set all the fields from the action to equal the field from the model though ... :(

Answer (score 0):

A popular method to solve this sort of problem is to create View Models used for representing the data required by the view.  Then using something like [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) or [Value injector](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) to make the mappings between the Domain Model and the View Model (which removes a lot of tedious code).  This approach also helps you avoid [Over-Posting / mass assignment attacks](http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/01/31/web-security-in-mvc4-net4-5-with-c-mass-assignment-aka-overposting/).